# Почему я не могу добиться нужного размера для svg-иконки с помощью viewBox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, svg

Я хочу, чтобы моя иконка была 25рх по ширине и 25рх по высоте.

Для этого я прописываю соответствующий viewport (`width: 25px; height: 25px;`) и viewBox (`viewBox="0 0 25 25"`).

Итак, мой масштаб 1:1.

Иконка должна быть ровно 25*25.

Но на самом деле этого почему-то не происходит – иконка не отображается целиком.

В чем может быть дело?

```css
.instagram_logo {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 12px;
  fill: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #2f3c4d;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 25 25" class="instagram_logo">
  <g>
                    <path d="M122.406,0H46.654C20.929,0,0,20.93,0,46.655v75.752c0,25.726,20.929,46.655,46.654,46.655h75.752
                    c25.727,0,46.656-20.93,46.656-46.655V46.655C169.063,20.93,148.133,0,122.406,0z M154.063,122.407
                    c0,17.455-14.201,31.655-31.656,31.655H46.654C29.2,154.063,15,139.862,15,122.407V46.655C15,29.201,29.2,15,46.654,15h75.752
                    c17.455,0,31.656,14.201,31.656,31.655V122.407z"/>
                    <path d="M84.531,40.97c-24.021,0-43.563,19.542-43.563,43.563c0,24.02,19.542,43.561,43.563,43.561s43.563-19.541,43.563-43.561
                    C128.094,60.512,108.552,40.97,84.531,40.97z M84.531,113.093c-15.749,0-28.563-12.812-28.563-28.561
                    c0-15.75,12.813-28.563,28.563-28.563s28.563,12.813,28.563,28.563C113.094,100.281,100.28,113.093,84.531,113.093z"/>
                    <path d="M129.921,28.251c-2.89,0-5.729,1.17-7.77,3.22c-2.051,2.04-3.23,4.88-3.23,7.78c0,2.891,1.18,5.73,3.23,7.78
                    c2.04,2.04,4.88,3.22,7.77,3.22c2.9,0,5.73-1.18,7.78-3.22c2.05-2.05,3.22-4.89,3.22-7.78c0-2.9-1.17-5.74-3.22-7.78
                    C135.661,29.421,132.821,28.251,129.921,28.251z"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: @Alexandr_TT да, было бы хорошо. Вы хорошо объясняете по темам svg:))))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Что произошло в ваше примере?
Иконка имеет физические размеры (как она была нарисована в векторном редакторе) явно больше чем 25 x 25px.
Поэтому при`viewBox = "0 0 25 25"` была захвачена только верхняя левая часть иконки, остальное обрезалась.
При `width="25px" height="25px"` (это viewport) масштаб действительно будет **1:1**

Но будет показана только эта видимая (необрезанная) часть изображения

Чтобы иконка не обрезалась, как в вашем случае или не имела лишних свободных полей вокруг изображения, необходимо точно узнать   габаритные размеры изображения и указать их в 3, 4 параметре `viewBox`

Поможет вычислить габаритные размеры метод JS [getBBox()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox)

```js
var svg = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
var bbox = svg.getBBox();
console.log(bbox);
```

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"   class="instagram_logo" >
  <g>
                    <path d="M122.406,0H46.654C20.929,0,0,20.93,0,46.655v75.752c0,25.726,20.929,46.655,46.654,46.655h75.752
                    c25.727,0,46.656-20.93,46.656-46.655V46.655C169.063,20.93,148.133,0,122.406,0z M154.063,122.407
                    c0,17.455-14.201,31.655-31.656,31.655H46.654C29.2,154.063,15,139.862,15,122.407V46.655C15,29.201,29.2,15,46.654,15h75.752
                    c17.455,0,31.656,14.201,31.656,31.655V122.407z"/>
                    <path d="M84.531,40.97c-24.021,0-43.563,19.542-43.563,43.563c0,24.02,19.542,43.561,43.563,43.561s43.563-19.541,43.563-43.561
                    C128.094,60.512,108.552,40.97,84.531,40.97z M84.531,113.093c-15.749,0-28.563-12.812-28.563-28.561
                    c0-15.75,12.813-28.563,28.563-28.563s28.563,12.813,28.563,28.563C113.094,100.281,100.28,113.093,84.531,113.093z"/>
                    <path d="M129.921,28.251c-2.89,0-5.729,1.17-7.77,3.22c-2.051,2.04-3.23,4.88-3.23,7.78c0,2.891,1.18,5.73,3.23,7.78
                    c2.04,2.04,4.88,3.22,7.77,3.22c2.9,0,5.73-1.18,7.78-3.22c2.05-2.05,3.22-4.89,3.22-7.78c0-2.9-1.17-5.74-3.22-7.78
                    C135.661,29.421,132.821,28.251,129.921,28.251z"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Таким образом мы узнали параметры `viewBox = "0 0 169 169"`

Теперь остается задать размеры иконки во viewport, которые будет видеть пользователь.

Необходимо показать иконку размером `25 x 25px`?

Это можно сделать двумя способами:

1. Указать непосредственно в шапке SVG

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="25px" height="25px" viewBox="0 0 169 169"   class="instagram_logo"  >
  <g>
                    <path d="M122.406,0H46.654C20.929,0,0,20.93,0,46.655v75.752c0,25.726,20.929,46.655,46.654,46.655h75.752
                    c25.727,0,46.656-20.93,46.656-46.655V46.655C169.063,20.93,148.133,0,122.406,0z M154.063,122.407
                    c0,17.455-14.201,31.655-31.656,31.655H46.654C29.2,154.063,15,139.862,15,122.407V46.655C15,29.201,29.2,15,46.654,15h75.752
                    c17.455,0,31.656,14.201,31.656,31.655V122.407z"/>
                    <path d="M84.531,40.97c-24.021,0-43.563,19.542-43.563,43.563c0,24.02,19.542,43.561,43.563,43.561s43.563-19.541,43.563-43.561
                    C128.094,60.512,108.552,40.97,84.531,40.97z M84.531,113.093c-15.749,0-28.563-12.812-28.563-28.561
                    c0-15.75,12.813-28.563,28.563-28.563s28.563,12.813,28.563,28.563C113.094,100.281,100.28,113.093,84.531,113.093z"/>
                    <path d="M129.921,28.251c-2.89,0-5.729,1.17-7.77,3.22c-2.051,2.04-3.23,4.88-3.23,7.78c0,2.891,1.18,5.73,3.23,7.78
                    c2.04,2.04,4.88,3.22,7.77,3.22c2.9,0,5.73-1.18,7.78-3.22c2.05-2.05,3.22-4.89,3.22-7.78c0-2.9-1.17-5.74-3.22-7.78
                    C135.661,29.421,132.821,28.251,129.921,28.251z"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

2. Либо указать в родительском контейнере

```css
.instagram_logo {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 12px;
  fill: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #2f3c4d;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 169 169"   class="instagram_logo"  >
  <g>
                    <path d="M122.406,0H46.654C20.929,0,0,20.93,0,46.655v75.752c0,25.726,20.929,46.655,46.654,46.655h75.752
                    c25.727,0,46.656-20.93,46.656-46.655V46.655C169.063,20.93,148.133,0,122.406,0z M154.063,122.407
                    c0,17.455-14.201,31.655-31.656,31.655H46.654C29.2,154.063,15,139.862,15,122.407V46.655C15,29.201,29.2,15,46.654,15h75.752
                    c17.455,0,31.656,14.201,31.656,31.655V122.407z"/>
                    <path d="M84.531,40.97c-24.021,0-43.563,19.542-43.563,43.563c0,24.02,19.542,43.561,43.563,43.561s43.563-19.541,43.563-43.561
                    C128.094,60.512,108.552,40.97,84.531,40.97z M84.531,113.093c-15.749,0-28.563-12.812-28.563-28.561
                    c0-15.75,12.813-28.563,28.563-28.563s28.563,12.813,28.563,28.563C113.094,100.281,100.28,113.093,84.531,113.093z"/>
                    <path d="M129.921,28.251c-2.89,0-5.729,1.17-7.77,3.22c-2.051,2.04-3.23,4.88-3.23,7.78c0,2.891,1.18,5.73,3.23,7.78
                    c2.04,2.04,4.88,3.22,7.77,3.22c2.9,0,5.73-1.18,7.78-3.22c2.05-2.05,3.22-4.89,3.22-7.78c0-2.9-1.17-5.74-3.22-7.78
                    C135.661,29.421,132.821,28.251,129.921,28.251z"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 7):

Вам ***не нужно менять значение viewBox вручную***, достаточно будет поместить сам SVG в контейнер и управлять его размером уже оттуда.

В данном случае `div` это Ваша подложка, а `svg` это только "изображение".

Т.е Вы можете спокойно и предсказуемо управлять каждым из них:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #2f3c4d;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: auto;
  fill: #ffffff;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 169.06 169.06">
  <g>
    <path d="M162.88,40.47H87.12A46.71,46.71,0,0,0,40.47,87.12v75.75a46.71,46.71,0,0,0,46.65,46.65h75.75a46.71,46.71,0,0,0,46.66-46.65V87.12A46.71,46.71,0,0,0,162.88,40.47Zm31.66,122.41a31.69,31.69,0,0,1-31.66,31.65H87.12a31.69,31.69,0,0,1-31.65-31.65V87.12A31.69,31.69,0,0,1,87.12,55.47h75.75a31.69,31.69,0,0,1,31.66,31.65v75.75Z" transform="translate(-40.47 -40.47)"/>
    <path d="M125,81.44A43.56,43.56,0,1,0,168.56,125,43.61,43.61,0,0,0,125,81.44Zm0,72.12A28.56,28.56,0,1,1,153.56,125,28.59,28.59,0,0,1,125,153.56Z" transform="translate(-40.47 -40.47)"/>
    <path d="M170.39,68.72a11,11,0,1,0,7.78,3.22A11,11,0,0,0,170.39,68.72Z" transform="translate(-40.47 -40.47)"/>
  </g>
  </svg>  
</div>
```